# C# Returning values from a list of classes

Tags: c#

I have a class that's basically like this:

```
class myClass
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
}
```

If I have a `List<myClass>`, how can I get `myClass.name` when searching for it's corresponding `myClass.id`.

Comment: using linq: myClasses.Where(c => c.id == "id_goes_here").SingleOrDefault().name. Though you'll probably want better handling for the null case

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it.

Search your class list using where.

Get the FirstOrDefault() element.

If an element is found, First or Default returns it, otherwise it returns null. Check for null, if the element is not null, get the name.

```
void Main()
{
    List<myClass> classList = new List<myClass>();
    classList.Add(new myClass(){id="1", name="A"});
    classList.Add(new myClass(){id="2", name="B"});
    classList.Add(new myClass(){id="3", name="C"});
    classList.Add(new myClass(){id="4", name="D"});
    classList.Add(new myClass(){id="5", name="E"});

    var element = classList.Where(t=>t.id=="5").FirstOrDefault();
    if(element != null)
    {
      var name = element.name;
      Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

class myClass
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks!

Comment: since we're talking about ids, hopefully this is functional. However, if in the future you wanted to grab against something that should be unique but there are no controls to enforce that, you'd end up snagging the first of such item. So if you needed to grab the account for jdoe@domain.com but they accidentally created a 2nd account with that email address, you'd pull the first instance of it in essence having the 2nd in limbo.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But the question is also talking about name of a single item.

Comment: @Amit you're right, not trying to correct you here, just more cautionary for in the future when choosing between Single and First (case by case, really). If someone becomes accustomed to First, they may not use Single when necessary and have unintended effects.

Comment: The id's will indeed be unique. So in this case First will always be correct.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ extension methods can do this pretty simply.

```
var classes = new List<myClass>();
classes.AddRange(classesToAdd);

var foundClassName = classes.Single(x => x.id == idToSearchFor).name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I need a little more to go on...you should post some code where you are trying...otherwise you're going to get guess-answers...but anyway:

```
var list = new List<myClass>();
//add entries

var name = list.First( x => x.id == myId ).name;
```

If nulls are a potential, you can use FirstOrDefault and null conditional operator:

```
var name = list.FirstOrDefault( x => x.id == myId)?.name;
```